# How can I use different image formats for different exports in org-mode?

Tags: image-processing, org-mode

I'd like to include inline images in my org-mode documents, but I really need a png for HTML export and a pdf for LaTeX export for it to look decent.  Is there a way to express this?

Comment: There's a thread on conditional export here: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2010-10/msg01143.html

Answer (score 6):

I got an answer in irc that worked well for me.

```
#+ATTR_LaTeX: width=0.38\textwidth wrap placement={r}{0.4\textwidth}
#+ATTR_HTML: alt="old index mech" title="Old index mech" align="right"
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :exports results :results value raw
(case (and (boundp 'backend) backend)
  (nil "")
  (latex "[[file:img/indexing-old.pdf]]")
  (html "[[file:img/indexing-old.png]]"))
#+end_src
```

This selects the link based on the backend at export time while still giving me HTML and LaTeX attributes.  Seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: Does it require additional setting? For me, this only prints « nil » in the exported documents.

Answer (score 0):

The elisp code below with conditionals works for me without any additional settings. When exporting to html, it exports an interactive iframe as an image. When exporting to odt or docx via pandoc, it exports a png version of it.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :exports results :results raw
(cond 
  ((org-export-derived-backend-p org-export-current-backend 'html)
   "#+HTML: <iframe src='./media/image.html' width='100%' height='400px' frameborder='0'></iframe>")
  ((org-export-derived-backend-p org-export-current-backend 'odt)
   "[[file:./media/image.png]]")
  (t "[[file:./media/image.png]]"))
#+END_SRC
```

If you want to keep the org export caption and cross-referencing functionality, you can add a dummy image (small transparent png):

```
#+CAPTION: Legend of image.
#+NAME:   fig:image
[[./media/dummy.png]]
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :exports results :results raw
(cond 
  ((org-export-derived-backend-p org-export-current-backend 'html)
   "#+HTML: <iframe src='./media/image.html' width='100%' height='400px' frameborder='0'></iframe>")
  ((org-export-derived-backend-p org-export-current-backend 'odt)
   "[[file:./media/image.png]]")
  (t "[[file:./media/image.png]]"))
#+END_SRC
```